# Name field type change for custom objects which are already used in a managed package showing error

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, metadata, 1gp-package

To practice the managed package, I created a package that is a simple app from one org and installed it in another. In the packaging org, all the Name field's type for the custom objects were set to Auto. The type was not updatable in the orgs where the package was installed or in the packaging org, that is why I created a third org and fixed the Name field type from Auto to Text. But I can't deploy the meta file in the packaging org anymore, it is showing the below error

> facing problem deploying in org. Cannot modify managed object:
> entity=CustomEntityDefinition, component=01I2r000000Pac4,
> field=OptionsFlagNameAutoNumber, state=released

What is the best possible way to fix it without creating another packaging org?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a package using 1GP([First generation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_release.htm)) where one uses packaging org to create a package (instead of the local source code), certain attributes are Locked once the package is Managed-Released. There are rules that lock these attributes. These rules are called `manageability` rules.

> This is necessary to make sure your package upgrade does not break your subscriber who might have additional customization based on this field.

There is a published list of what is locked for Each Metadata Type [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=packaging_component_attributes.htm&type=5).

Changing From Auto Number to Regular Text for ***Name*** field is not allowed once your package is Managed Released.

What are your options?

1. Raise a support case with Salesforce, and they can help revert your package to a BETA State, and then you can easily change a few of those locked attributes.
2. Instead of using 1GP packaging use [2GP packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm), which allows you to abandon a package and create a new package with the same namespace.
3. Last option is to create a new packaging org with the new namespace. It is really not an option if you have a package that subscribers are using because this will change the schema and namespace.